# Как можно оптимизировать данный код

Tags: python

Данный код дешифратор шифра gronsfeld на python каким образом можно ускорить его до максимума ? Программа берет ключ через цикл начиная с 0 и по ключу подбирает слова, слова сравниваются со словарем из 500.000 словами.

```
def algo(text, k, op):
    k *= len(text) // len(k) + 1
    return ''.join(alph[alph.index(j) + int(k[i]) * op] for i, j in enumerate(text))


def encrypt(message, key):
    return algo(message, key, 1)

for x in range(1000000):
    f = open('words.txt')
    s = decrypt('DWDTYFM', str(x))
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip('\n')
        if s.lower() == line.lower():
            print(line)
```

Comment: Положите все слова в set. И просто проверяйте наличие в нём.

Comment: Да, считайте файл заранее в память, поместите слова из него в множество. Так хотя бы на этом сэкономите. А вот функцию `decrypt` вы не показали, поэтому неизвестно, как её можно оптимизировать. Показанные вами функции `encrypt` и `algo` в вашем коде не используются.